# MongoDB: Avoid that some fields are present in the Query Result

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a database schema that looks like:

```
{
  foreignKeyId: String
  question: String
  ...: ...
  answers: [
    {
       answerText: String
       isCorrect: Boolean
    }
    ,
    ...
  ]
}
```

I now want a find()-Query that queries a document by foreignKeyId and only  contains the fields foreignKeyId, question and answers.$.answerText.

As I use MeteorJS I am not able to return anything else than a cursor to the database.

When I filter it like `{fields: {foreignKeyId: 1, "answers.$.answerText":1}}` I get an error that the projection does not match my Query

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

It is not

```
db.find(query, {fields: {"array.$.subkey": 1}});
```

it is

```
db.find(query, {fields: {"array.subkey": 1}});
```